# deploy .net 7 rest service in linux (shared bluehost and ionos)

Tags: .net, linux, rest, deployment, self-contained

I have a simple .NET 7 REST API service that only contains the default WeatherForecastController. This controller is automatically generated when creating a new project. That's it. I intentionally kept it simple without any databases or other stuff.
I compiled it using the "self-contained, linux x-64" options and successfully ran it on my local Linux distribution (Ubuntu).

However, when attempting to run the app on a shared hosting plan (such as Bluehost or Ionos), I encountered an error message: "Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E." Although both hosts have free memory available, it seems to be a memory issue.

For instance, I purchased a plan with ample RAM(20giga) and SSD(500giga) on Ionos, but the problem persists.
I also have granted read, write, and execute permissions to all files.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to make a crash dump? might give you hints why the error happened

Comment: Not really. Look here (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13027 or https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/php-exec-failed-to-create-coreclr/39602), it seems like a provider problem, probably with the majority of shared hosting providers. Shared hosting doesn't work  well in this case  because you don't have full control of your machine. Moreover, if you try to remove the memory limit, the providers block this action